# On $e^{5x}+e^{4x}+e^{3x}+e^{2x}+e^{x}+1$

Tags: sequences-and-series, power-series, exponential-function, bernoulli-numbers

Define the following,

$$F_2(x) := \frac{1}{2}+\frac{(2x)}{1!} B_2\Big(\tfrac{1}{2}\Big)+\frac{(2x)^2}{2!}B_3\Big(\tfrac{1}{2}\Big)+\frac{(2x)^3}{3!}B_4\Big(\tfrac{1}{2}\Big)+\dots $$

$$\color{brown}{F_3(x)} := \frac{1}{3}+\frac{(3x)}{1!} B_2\Big(\tfrac{1}{3}\Big)+\frac{(3x)^2}{2!}B_3\Big(\tfrac{1}{3}\Big)+\frac{(3x)^3}{3!}B_4\Big(\tfrac{1}{3}\Big)+\dots $$

$$F_4(x) := \frac{1}{4}+\frac{(4x)}{1!} B_2\Big(\tfrac{1}{4}\Big)+\frac{(4x)^2}{2!}B_3\Big(\tfrac{1}{4}\Big)+\frac{(4x)^3}{3!}B_4\Big(\tfrac{1}{4}\Big)+\dots $$

$$\color{brown}{F_6(x)}  := \frac{1}{6}+\frac{(6x)}{1!} B_2\Big(\tfrac{1}{6}\Big)+\frac{(6x)^2}{2!}B_3\Big(\tfrac{1}{6}\Big)+\frac{(6x)^3}{3!}B_4\Big(\tfrac{1}{6}\Big)+\dots $$

From *Summation of Series* (2nd ed) by L.B Jolley, page 26, it seems that,

$$\color{brown}{F_3(x)} \overset{?}= \frac{1}{1+e^x+e^{2x}}\\
\color{brown}{F_6(x)} \overset{?}= \frac{1}{1+e^{x}+e^{2x}+e^{3x}+e^{4x}+e^{5x}}\tag1$$

I assume that $B_n(x)$ are the *Bernoulli polynomials*. However, when I try to numerically evaluate those two $F_k(x)$ using *Mathematica*, the LHS does not agree with the RHS.

**Questions:**

1. How to interpret $B(n)$ such that $(1)$ holds true?
2. And do $F_2(x)$ and $F_4(x)$ evaluate similar to $(1)$?

Comment: There is a pdf copy of the cited book, ***Summation of Series*** at [this link](http://plouffe.fr/simon/math/SummationofSeries.pdf).

Comment: It's pretty clear $B_n(x)$ does not signify Bernoulli polynomials, or else some other error is present.  The second term of the power series for $(1+e^x+e^{2x})^{-1}$ is $-\frac{x}{3}$, while $B_2(\frac{1}{3})=-\frac{1}{18}$.

Comment: @vadim123: However, the author _does_ mention _Bernoulli numbers_ in a related page, but I think he affixes a multiplicative factor.

Comment: This book is extremely confusing (at least, to me).

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici: I know. But the two "identities" are too beautiful (imho) and too consistent in form to be make-believe. There has to be a way to make it work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Ad Question 1:** The polynomials $B_n(x)$ defined in L.B.W. Jolley's book *[Summation of Series](http://plouffe.fr/simon/math/SummationofSeries.pdf)* are close relatives of the *[Bernoulli polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_polynomials)* defined e.g. in L. Comtet's classic *[Advanced Combinatorics](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/9027703809)* but not the same.

To differentiate the polynomials defined in L.B.W. Jolley's book from the more commonly defined Bernoulli polynomials we use, we denote them from now on with $\widetilde{B}_n$.

> In number (1128) on p. 228 in Jolley's book and in the subsequent section (1129) we find a representation of $\widetilde{B}_n(x)$ as generating series.
>   \begin{align*}
> t\frac{e^{xt}-1}{e^x-1}=\sum_{n\geq 1}n\widetilde{B}_n(x)\frac{t^n}{n!}\tag{1}
> \end{align*}
>
> A generating function of the *[Bernoulli polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_polynomials)* $B_n(x)$ is given as
>   \begin{align*}
> t\frac{e^{xt}}{e^t-1}=\sum_{n\geq 0}B_n(x)\frac{t^n}{n!}
> \end{align*}
>   Since a generating function of the *[Bernoulli numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_number)* $B_n=B_n(0)$ is
>   \begin{align*}
> \frac{t}{e^t-1}=\sum_{n\geq 0}B_n(0)\frac{t^n}{n!}
> \end{align*}
>
> we obtain the following relationship between *Bernoulli polynomials* $B_n(x)$ and $\widetilde{B}_n(x)$
>
> \begin{align*}
> \widetilde{B}_n(x)=\frac{B_n(x)-B_n(0)}{n}\qquad\qquad n\geq 1
> \end{align*}

**Ad question 2:** The answer is affirmative. The nice formulas of $F_t(x)$ are valid for all $t\in \mathbb{N}$.

> On one hand we obtain for $t\geq 1$ by expanding numerator and denominator of $F_t(x)$ with $1-e^x$
>
> \begin{align*}
> F_t(x)&=\frac{1}{1+e^x+e^{2x}+\cdots+e^{(t-1)x}}\\
> &=\frac{1-e^x}{1-e^{xt}}
> \end{align*}

On the other hand note, that the general expression of $F_t(x)$ is
\begin{align*}
F_t(x)=\frac{1}{t}+\sum_{n\geq 1}\widetilde{B}_{n+1}\left(\frac{1}{t}\right)\frac{(tx)^n}{n!}\tag{2}
\end{align*}

> We obtain
>
> \begin{align*}
> F_t(x)&=\frac{1}{t}+\sum_{n\geq 1}\widetilde{B}_{n+1}\left(\frac{1}{t}\right)\frac{(tx)^n}{n!}\\
> &=\frac{1}{t}+\sum_{n\geq 2}\widetilde{B}_n\left(\frac{1}{t}\right)\frac{(tx)^{n-1}}{(n-1)!}\\
> &=\frac{1}{t}+\frac{1}{tx}\sum_{n\geq 2}n\widetilde{B}_n\left(\frac{1}{t}\right)\frac{(tx)^{n}}{n!}\tag{3}\\
> &=\frac{1}{t}+\frac{1}{tx}\left(tx\frac{e^{\frac{1}{t}tx}-1}{e^{tx}-1}-\widetilde{B_1}\left(\frac{1}{t}\right)tx\right)\tag{4}\\
> &=\frac{1}{t}+\frac{1}{tx}\left(tx\frac{e^x-1}{e^{tx}-1}-x\right)\\
> &=\frac{e^x-1}{e^{tx}-1}\\
> \end{align*}
>
> and the claim follows.

*Comment:*

- In (3) we use the generating series for $n\widetilde{B}_n(x)$ according to (1)
- In (4) note that $\widetilde{B}_1(x)=x$

> **Epilogue:**
>
> *Symmetry*
>
> The Function $F_t(x)$ and its reciprocal $\frac{1}{F_t(x)}$ admit a nice nearly symmetrical representation with respect to Bernoulli polynomials and their arguments. The following is valid
>
> \begin{align*}
> F_t(x)-1&
> =\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{B_{n+1}\left(\frac{1}{t}\right)-B_{n+1}(0)}{n+1}\frac{(tx)^n}{n!}\\
> \frac{1}{F_t(x)}&
> =\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{B_{n+1}(t)-B_{n+1}(0)}{n+1}\frac{x^n}{n!}
> \end{align*}

This holds, since according to (2) we get
\begin{align*}
F_t(x)&=\frac{1}{\sum_{k=0}^{t-1}e^{kx}}
=\frac{1}{t}+\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{B_{n+1}\left(\frac{1}{t}\right)-B_{n+1}(0)}{n+1}\frac{(tx)^n}{n!}\\
&=1+\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{B_{n+1}\left(\frac{1}{t}\right)-B_{n+1}(0)}{n+1}\frac{(tx)^n}{n!}\\
\end{align*}
and
\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{F_t(x)}&=\sum_{k=0}^{t-1}e^{kx}
=\sum_{k=0}^{t-1}\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{(kx)^n}{n!}
=\sum_{n\geq 0}\left(\sum_{k=0}^{t-1}k^n\right)\frac{x^n}{n!}\\
&=\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{B_{n+1}(t)-B_{n+1}(0)}{n+1}\frac{x^n}{n!}
\end{align*}

> *Historical Note*
>
> The definition of the Bernoulli numbers $\widetilde{B}_n$ in L.B.W. Jolley's book is taken from the *British Association Report* from 1877. The first few numbers are
>
> \begin{array}{cccccccccc}
> n&0&1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8\\
> \hline\\
> \widetilde{B}_n&-1&\frac{1}{6}&\frac{1}{30}&\frac{1}{42}&\frac{1}{30}
> &\frac{5}{66}&\frac{691}{2730}&\frac{7}{6}&\frac{3617}{510}\\
> \\
> B_n&0&-\frac{1}{2}&\frac{1}{6}&0&-\frac{1}{30}&0&\frac{1}{42}&0&-\frac{1}{30}
> \end{array}
>
> This corresponds for $n\geq 1$ to Comtet's statement in section 1.14
>
> (notation somewhat adapted) ... Bernoulli numbers, denoted by $b_n$ by Bourbaki, are sometimes also defined by:
>   \begin{align*}
> \frac{t}{e^t-1}=1-\frac{1}{2}t+\sum_{n\geq 1}(-1)^{n+1}B_n\frac{t^{2n}}{(2n)!}
> \end{align*}
>
> Each $B_n$ is then $>0$ and equals $(-1)^{n+1}B_{2n}$ as a function of our Bournoulli numbers.

Comment: Thanks! I knew it was connected to the Bernoulli polynomials. It's good to know the formulas in fact work for all $t\in \mathbb{N}$. (In Jolley's book, he showed only $t = 3,6$ and I assumed, from my work on [pi formulas](https://sites.google.com/site/tpiezas/0027) with _Pochhammer symbol_ $\left(\tfrac{1}{2}\right)_n, \left(\tfrac{1}{3}\right)_n, \left(\tfrac{1}{4}\right)_n, \left(\tfrac{1}{6}\right)_n$, that there might be for $t = 2,3,4,6$.)

Comment: @TitoPiezasIII: You're welcome. Thanks for the link to your web pages. Very nice to go through them! :-) I've added an epilogue addressing one more *beautiful* algebraic aspect and a historical note. Best regards,

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici: I've added an answer which might be interesting for you.

Comment: I'm glad you liked my webpages.  :)